# Could not load file or assembly error when running ASP.NET web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

I am developing a Xamarin.Forms app with ASP.NET Web Api with VS2019.

Somehow I when I run the web api project I am getting this error regarding
Xamarin.Forms.Xaml which has no reference to it in my web api.

Could not load file or assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' could not be loaded.

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Xamarin.Forms.Xaml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/Malcolm/Documents/Visual Studio 2019/Projects/LakesLinenOrdersApp/LakesLinenOrdersApi/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Users\Malcolm\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\LakesLinenOrdersApp\LakesLinenOrdersApi\bin
Calling assembly : GUI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.

This is the Stack Trace:

[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext) +151
   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments) +135
   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg) +92
   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent) +502
   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, RuntimeType caType) +108
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(Boolean inherit) +40
   Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.SearchForStartupAttribute(String friendlyName, IList`1 errors, Boolean& conflict) +106
   Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.GetDefaultConfiguration(String friendlyName, IList`1 errors) +46
   Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.LoadImplementation(String startupName, IList`1 errorDetails) +75
   Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.Load(String startupName, IList`1 errorDetails) +21
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.GetAppStartup() +115
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint() +28
   System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) +119
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context) +106
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +552
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +181
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +228
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +314

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10085052
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +99
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +263

Comment: What references does it have? Does it have, for example, a reference to another project that does have a reference to Xamarin Forms?

Comment: No there isnt that i can see. What i have tried is to remove the web api project from the solution but when i double click the web api project file it is still opening the solution it once was in. Why??

Comment: That's because the web api project file is still at the same folder with the solution . You should check the reference of the web api project. You can try copy the web api project file to another new folder and open it again.